# find command says: unknown group XYZ

Tags: files, command-line

This question is the next part of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111126/camera-group-not-found-in-android-groups). I'm trying to use `find` command (Android 4.2.1; Busybox installed, have root access) to list files owned by a specific group under `/`, but every time I use it I get the same reply. E.g. I'm trying to find all the files owned by group `adb` using `find / -group adb` and the output says:

> find: unknown group adb

I tried both single-double quotes but no effect. Tried for other groups but no effect again.

How should I use `find` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of using find is correct.

However there is no group "adb".

Run `id -p` to get all groups. You will get

> groupid(name)

Then run `find / -group <groupid>`.

> The groupid is an integer.

Comment: +1. It works. I was just focusing on the name considering this `-group NAME/ID  File is owned by given group` while it was supposed to be ID that needed to be passed. Could you mention what would be passed as `NAME`?

Comment: Could you also take a look at a similar questions [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111126/camera-group-not-found-in-android-groups)? That would be very helpful.