# How can I find the group id (gid) for the sdcard_r group on android?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

The question says it all. All folders on my sdcard has owner set as 0(root) and group set as `sdcard_r` - means all apps that have permissions to access the sdcard.

However, since I have root, I want to change the group of this folder using `chgrp`, so that only a selected app can access this. I know how to do this too, so no probs until now.

However, I don't want this to be a one-way setting, I want to be able to revert back to `sdcard_r` in case something goes wrong. Now I don't know the actual gid of this group sdcard_r and chgrp only works with gids, not names. So, how can I find the gid of this group, sdcard_r?

Comment: Weird, I don't even see a `sdcard_r` group listed in Root Explorer on my devices...

Comment: What group do you see assigned to a random folder on sdcard (such as `/mnt/sdcard/foo`) in the root explorer?

Comment: 9997, which doesn't have a corresponding name in the list.

Comment: k, and if you open a terminal app and go to the sdcard folder and perform `ls -al`, what group does it show there? (In my case its `sdcard`).

Comment: What does `id sdcard_r` and `id -G sdcard_r` returns?

Comment: @PrahladYeri “everybody”, which should actually be 9999. Weird.

Comment: @Firelord uid, gid, groups are all 1028 on my device. I don't know what it can be for OP.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord, the id command shows 1028 gid for me too, but the problem is `chgrp` isn't working when I try to change the group, and nor does `chmod 0:10066` change it. But I guess that's besides the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command to see GID of the concerned group:

```
id -G group_name
```

Courtesy of [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111138/96277) of doylefermi.

It is very much possible that the GID would be 1028 given [this line in source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#72) of Android.